# How to validate a password field for a specific password?

Tags: android

How to validate a password field for a specific password, say `coolhack`, as in this case in Android?

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttn;
    EditText passwrd;
    String str, str1 = "coolhack";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        passwrd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        str = passwrd.getText().toString();
        buttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate() {
        if(str.equals(str1)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INVALID PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All i get is a Toast saying INVALID PASSWORD despite having entered coolhack as input!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttn;
    EditText passwrd;
    String str, str1 = "coolhack";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        passwrd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        buttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str = passwrd.getText().toString().trim();
                validate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate() {
        if(str.equals(str1)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INVALID PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Get the string from edittext when we click on the button.

Comment: @cricket_007 my bad didn't saw the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move

```
str = passwrd.getText().toString();
```

inside the onClick (or validate method)

Currently, you're immediately getting an empty string when the Activity is loaded.

You want to *react* to the later input